# HTML5 input validation doesn't work in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

Hello kind people of the internet,
I've been hacking at this for a while...and have seen several similar postings, but I can't seem to figure this out:

The HTML5 input field validation CSS works in Firefox, Chrome...but alas, not in IE8...and much of my target audience will be using IE8.

...and yes: I'm using Modernizr, and I used Initializr to get the page template and CSS...I'm a bit confused why I can't get things working properly in IE8.

Here's a link to my test page:
[Test html5 page](http://www.msa.saccounty.net/utilitybilling/streetview/TestHTML5pagev6.aspx)

The input field is red before proper entry, then validation simply turns green when input a valid account number, such as:
50011111111

The HTML5 code is as follows:

```
<label for="account">Account Number: </label> 
<input id="account" name="inputAccount" 
  placeholder="input billing account number" 
  pattern="/(^500)|^\d{11}" 
  required
  autofocus
  type="text"/>
```

Any suggestions on what is probably a fairly simple thing to fix would be mucho appreciated!

Comment: Check out [jQuery Tools Validator](http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/) which will use HTML5 attributes on your form inputs for validation and is compatible with IE7, IE8 and later.

Comment: For me [formality](http://lingerbird.com/projects/open-source/formality/) works on IE6 too.

Comment: @apaidnerd link is not working

Comment: @Patriks link is not working getting 404

Answer (score 13):

IE just ignors HTML5 elements because it dosen't know about them. From the Modernizr docs

> Modernizr runs through a little loop in JavaScript to enable the
>   various elements from HTML5 (as well as abbr) for styling in Internet
>   Explorer. Note that this does not mean it suddenly makes IE support
>   the Audio or Video element, it just means that you can use section
>   instead of div and style them in CSS.

What this says is that Modernizr will tell IE about the new tags in HTML5 so that you can use CSS on them, but dosen't actually make them do anything. Note too that Modernizr dosen't add default styles for the elements, so they recommend you use an HTML5 CSS reset that makes `<section>` tags `display: block;` for example.

With respect to your form validation topek was correct in explaining that Modernizr only detects browser capability, it dosen't actually do anything about it. The proccess behind Modernizr is that you use the built-in yepnope testing feature to see if the user's browser can do 'x' (in this case form validation) and then conditionally and asynchronously load a script or style to "polyfill" (a polite way of saying 'use javascript to mimic native behaviour) for it.

In your case, you will want to use `Modernizr.load()` to test for `Modernizr.input.required` and probably `Modernizr.input.autofocus` too, like this:

```
 //the modernizr conditional load function
 Modernizr.load({
     //specify the tests, refer to the Modernizr docs for object names
   test: Modernizr.input.required && Modernizr.input.placeholder,
     //specify what to do if the browser fails the test, can be a function
   nope: 'path/to/polyfill/script',
     //sometimes you need to run some JS to init that script
   complete: function(){ polyfillinitorwhatever(); }
 });
```

And there you go, a pretty stripped-down Modernizr.load. While I find their docs meandering, they actually are very good. Every time I've had a problem and tweeted at Paul Irish, he's sent back a link to the docs where I actually did find my answer upon closer inspection.

Validation is one of the most complex HTML5 features for the browser makers to implement as a standard. While I really like it's simplicity, I've been continuing to use jQuery.validate  in all cases except if the user has Chrome or Opera - the FF native validate is weak still. I'd recommend you stick with jQuery for now.

Answer (score 3):

I recently found a new plugin [jquery.h5form](https://github.com/rapidexp/jquery-h5form).

Using this, form validation, like in Opera, will be enabled in all browsers, even IE8.

Comment: There is another one [formality](http://lingerbird.com/projects/open-source/formality/), We only have to include JavaScript file, that's it. Works on IE6 too.

Comment: But formality only gives redbox, not specify the message

Comment: Hi there, I just wanted to downvote formality. I was using it fine, but then it actually didn't error in IE8 emulation from IE11, but did error in real IE8, and then all it does it redbox, and it didn't even validate properly. I was using a max, min, step validation and it worked fine in all browsers, including the IE emulation, since I already had some IE8 polyfill and was using old JS, everything validated fine with jQuery validate and unobstrusive validation. Formality however fudged things up and told me nothing but a red box, no error messages and no idea why it was doing that. removed,np

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are still missing, is a html5 polyfill for the field validation. You could use for example: http://ericleads.com/h5validate/

More polyfills can be found under: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: Hi, thanks much for the feed back...I will try some of the solutions above. Hmmm...but I'm already using/referencing Modernizr, which from I thought was suppose to fix all these cross browser issues so that native HTML5 worked transparently in all kinds of browsers, soooo dumb question(s): Why isn't Modernizr working in IE8? What good is Modernizer if it doesn't work in IE? Or am I perhaps simply not using Modernizr correctly?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not support all, if any, HTML5 elements. You need to have an addon for html5 to work. One addon is [modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/)

[List of browsers](http://html5test.com/results.html) with their score/compatibility in HTML5

Comment: My page is referencing Modernizr...that's the point of this post.  I'm  befuddled why Modernizr does not seem to work...

Comment: Modernizer won't do that work, it just checks which capabilities a browser has. You need a polyfill, see my answer.

Comment: if you go to http://www.modernizr.com/download/ you can download modernizer with polyfill included.