# IE8 'required' radio buttons

Tags: internet-explorer-8, required

I have huge problem, because my app must work properly on IE8. Could you tell me why `required` doesn't work on IE8? It works on Firefox. I have a lot of radio buttons and I need them to be `required`

```html
<tr>
    <td><input type='radio' name='check' value='0'></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='check' value='1' required></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='check' value='2'></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959955/html5-input-validation-doesnt-work-in-ie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 does not support the `[required]` form attribute. Support for this attribute was not added in Internet Explorer [until version 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772943(v=vs.85).aspx). In order to provide similar functionality downlevel, to older versions of Internet Explorer, I would encourage you to use something like [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), a well-trusted and time-tested approach to form validation in legacy browsers.